# Split string by n when n is random

Tags: python, split, slice

I'm trying to split a string by n, when n is random for each slice. So, the program would generate n, take the first n chars of the string and append them to a list, generate a new value for n, and then get the next n values of the string and repeat.

My existing code doesn't work as expected:

```
string = '1234567890'
splitted = []

prev = 0
while True:
    n = random.randint(1,3)
    splitted.append(string[0:n])
    prev = prev + n
    if prev >= len(string)-1:
        break
print splitted
```

Comment: Ok, so where is your code?and what's wrong with it?

Comment: My code so far isn't relevant. I'm coding a program and I just can't figure out how to implement the above.

Comment: What's wrong with what? o.O

Comment: I'm sure you can do it brute force.

Comment: Since SO is not a code writing service pls add your code and explain about it and your wrong output!

Comment: What do you want to do this for? It's entirely possible that there's an easier way to solve whatever problem it was that you were stuck on in the first place.

Comment: I need to get every n characters, but n will be different for every slice. How can I bruteforce that?

Comment: @Kasramvd, no offense, but you didn't understand the OP.

Comment: what if there are not enough characters left?

Comment: There will be enough characters, that's not a problem. I'm performing this on Pi.

Comment: are the slices always supposed to be sequential?

Comment: But for the sake of it, if there aren't enough characters, then just break.

Comment: do you mean something like http://pastebin.com/0hz0e7BQ

Comment: What do you mean? The string in the OP was just an example.

Comment: @Aurora You're the one who doesn't understand, and what you don't understand is the site rules. You code, you run into a specific issue, and maybe we can help. But "I want to do this thing and I have zero idea how to do it HELP" is just asking for someone to write code for you, for free. That's not what we do here. That's probably not what anyone does, anywhere.

Comment: I understand the site rules perfectly. I have asked a very specific programming question, and I'm hoping for answers. The question will help other users in the future too. In this particular case, I have no relevant code to provide, as my attempts so far have been unsuccessful. Providing code that does not work is illogical.

Comment: it's not entirely illogical. it helps us to tweak your code so that it can work. all in all it will help you pinpoint where and how you made your mistake. if the code is too bad and cannot be tweaked, then it shows that you're at least gave a solid try.

Comment: I understand, but in this case my attempts were hopeless. :P

Comment: I've appended my existing code.

Comment: "I understand the site rules perfectly." Judging by your -8 question score, 4 close votes, and the huge argument in the comments, I might suggest you give them another read.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I figured it out and posted the answer.

Comment: @Aurora I've reversed my vote. Sorry I can't do more. This is a good template for future questions though.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Thanks for your help, and for being reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
string = '123456789'
splitted = []

prev = 0
while True:
    n = random.randint(1,3)
    splitted.append(string[prev:prev+n])
    prev = prev + n
    if prev >= len(string)-1:
        break
print splitted
```

Answer (score 0):

This generator will do the trick:

```
def randSplit(word, splits):
    for splitLen in splits:
        if splitLen > len(word):
            break
        yield word[:splitLen]
        word = word[splitLen::]
```

You can use it like:

```
>>> print(list(randSplit("3.14159",[1,4,2])))
['3', '.141', '59']
>>> print(list(randSplit("3.14159",[1,4,3])))
['3', '.141']
```

Note that `splits` can be any iterator. If you want random split lengths to be taken you can use this iterator:

```
def randGen(low,hi):
    while True:
        yield random.randint(low,hi)
```

You can use it like:

```
>>> print(list(randSplit("1234567890",randGen(1,3))))
['123', '4', '5', '67', '89']
>>> print(list(randSplit("1234567890",randGen(1,3))))
['123', '456', '78', '9', '0']
```

Comment: I have to give it the values? I want it to split it by a random value, and each split will be randomly generated. So, it would generate a random number, say n, and then get the next n chars of the string, and generate another value for n, and so on.

Comment: @Aurora You can still do that! You just have to make a random number generator! I added code to illustrate this :)

Comment: That seems like it'd work, and it's a much more elegant solution than mine. I'll test it later when I'm at a PC.